# Accessing Methods and Properties of an Inherited Class in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, properties

Suppose I have a base and a derived class like this

```
class Student {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RollID { get; set; }
    public void GetPaint() { }
}
class Person : Student {
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public void GetGun() { }
}
class Content {
    public void method(Student student) {
        Student _student = student;
        Person _person = (Person)student;

    }
}
class Client
{       
    static void Main()
    {
        new Content().method(new Person() { Name="foo",RollID=1});
    }
}
```

Now in this code when Debug and hover my mouse over the parameter of the Method in the Content Class, I can see all the properties both of Student as well as the Person class

[image]
but when i try to access the method i can only access the method of the class Student. I have to cast it to Person in order to access the the method of the class Person.
My question is how is that i am able to see and retrieve the value of the property of the class Student which is the derived class of the class Person. Why am i able to see the value of the property which does not belong to the class Student? and why am i not able to access methods. Please explain, am in missing some concepts?

Comment: Logic wise, the Student should derive from the Person not the other way round. Your logic assumes that every person is a student which is not the case.

Comment: Student is not the derived class but the base class and Person is the derived class in this case

Comment: @NetUser101 class Person will have only the details of the Student. So when you pull the details of the student you will get the details of only the student not his personal details

Comment: You told the compiler that the object is a Student.  It has no way of knowing that it is actually a Person.  You used secret knowledge, the debugger told you, that's something the compiler cannot do.  And if it is *not* actually a Person but a Student object then your program will crash like a ton of bricks.  Which is why downcasts like that are a bad idea, favor polymorphism with the *virtual* keyword instead.

Comment: @HansPassant i am just trying to learn the mechanics of the framework

Comment: Standard object-oriented programming btw, nothing to do with the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I able to see the value of the property which does not belong to the class `Student`?

Because the debugger looks at the *actual* type (`Person` in this case) of the object and all of the properties, etc. associated with that type.

> why am I not able to access methods?

Because the *variable* is of type `Student`, all you're allowed to access are the members of `Student`.  If you want to access the members of a different type (e.g. `Person`), you have to *cast* to tell the compiler "treat this reference as if it refers to a `Person`".  If the `Student` is not really a `Person` at run-time, you'll get an exception.

Comment: well i know the reason why we are not able to access the methods of Person but my question is when we are not able to access the method of Person then why are we able to access only the Properties of Person when the parameter of the method int the class Context is of type Student

Comment: I'm confused - you are able to access the properties of `Person` AND `Student` _in the debugger_.  The debugger can look at the _actual_ type of the object at run-time which the compiler cannot do.

Comment: ok, so thats the reason i can see the values of the property of the class Person while debugging. i got that now

Answer (score 0):

You have your inheritance flipped. Just change your classes as follows:

```
class Person {
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public void GetGun() { }
}
class Student : Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RollID { get; set; }
    public void GetPaint() { }
}
```